# calabash-android how to create loops or iterate something until an exit condition?

Tags: android, loops, calabash

[image]I'm trying a seat selection process for a bus. I have a seat layout with some seats booked ans some not booked. I need to select an unbooked seat. I need to create a loop by tapping random coordinates on the screen till i am able to tap on a unbooked seat. how can this be done using calabash.

Comment: It is not clear how far you are in making this your self.
But you need a loop and instead of tapping randomly, why not detect where the seats are and tap them one at a time?

You could also query for all seats, and then tap them in a random order. If random testing is something you need.

Comment: In a single view the seats are loaded as bitmap images. How can i identify which seats are empty and which are not? booked and unbooked seats have different colors but i cannot use the color property to identify empty seats. Using the bitmap view id also does not work.

Comment: So when a seat is taken you change the color. Would it be possible to have some type on the seat as well that you could change? Something that calabash could pick up? Otherwise I would query for all seats, then the array of seats I would do an action on every single one of them.

Comment: first step would be to build a query which can discriminate between booked and unbooked seats. You might ask your dev team to add an attribute to the view for booked/unbooked status. Then you can programmatically interact with the UI.

Comment: Im writing a custom script in ruby which taps on different coordinates of the screen and checks for the fare value after each tap( by default which is 0.0) so that whenever the fare value changes i can know that a seat is booked, any suggestions how to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread is a bit old. But anyways here goes something along the lines of what you are looking for.

You want to touch a certain set of coordinates on the screen, see if you select a seat and then read the fare value.

So you need a loop. You can use something like this.
From you picture I can see that you only have 8 seats on there. But to make it quick lets just try and hit the the areas which also might have a seat and say that we are looking at 3x4 seats.

```
a = 0
b = 0
while a < 3
  while b < 4 
     b += 1
  end
  a += 1
end
```

The outer loop will run 3 times, that is from front to back. The inner loop will run 4 times, that is seats left to right.

Now we need to make sure that we click on each position, so we add

```
performAction('click_on_screen',<x-value>, <y-value>)
```

And combined we have something like this.
Where you have x and y that are starting positions and should match the coordinates of the first seat.
Then at first run you just click at that location and do what ever you need to get the fare price.
After first click you increase the xOffset value by the distance between the two seats, and then you are ready to click on the second one. Please keep in mind, that I made this simpler so actually the second press will touch on the isle. But on the 3rd and the 4th you should again hit the seats.
And then you do that for the two next rows afterwards.

```
a = 0
b = 0
x = 100
y = 500
xOffset = x;
while a < 3
  while b < 4  
     performAction('click_on_screen', xOffset, y)
     b += 1
     xOffset += 200 
  end
  xOffset = x
  y += 200
  a += 1
end
```

Best regards
Lasse

Comment: Thanks, though i had already figured it out and had done the same thing you mentioned here.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you had solved it. Out of curiosity, did you do random clicks then? Or figure out how to query the seats?

Comment: No i couldnt query seats, it was not possible so i had to implement random clicks only.